# Protect E-mail address from scraping on a static site generated by Gatsby

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

I have a static website that was written in Gatsby. There is an E-mail address on the website, which I want to protect from harvester bots.

My first approach was, that I send the E-mail address to the client-side using GraphQL. The sent data is encoded in base64 and I decode it on client-side in the React component where the E-mail address is displayed. But if I build the Gatsby site in production and take a look at the served `index.html` I can see the already decoded E-mail address in the html code. In production there seems to be no `XHR request` at all, so all GraphQL queries were evaluated while the server-side rendering was running.

So for the second approach, I tried to decode the E-mail address when the react component is mount.
This way the server-side rendered `html` page does not contain the E-mail address. But when the page is loaded it is displayed.

The relevant parts of the code look following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const Contacts = () => {
    const { site } = useStaticQuery(
        graphql`
          query {
            site {
                siteMetadata {
                    email
              }
            }
          }
        `
    )
    function decode(s) {
        var e = {}, i, b = 0, c, x, l = 0, a, r = '', w = String.fromCharCode, L = s.length;
        var A = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) { e[A.charAt(i)] = i; }
        for (x = 0; x < L; x++) {
            c = e[s.charAt(x)]; b = (b << 6) + c; l += 6;
            while (l >= 8) { ((a = (b >>> (l -= 8)) & 0xff) || (x < (L - 2))) && (r += w(a)); }
        }
        return r;
    };

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => decodeData(), []);
    function decodeData() {
        setEmail(() => decode(site.siteMetadata.email), []);
    }

    return (
        //...
        <span className="service-text">{email}</span>
        //...
    )
}


export default Contacts
```

Does this approach make any difference? I mean can I protect this way the E-mail address from the bots?
This way at least the requested `html` page does not contain the E-mail address hard coded.

If you would like to take a look at the page in the developer tools of a browser, it can be found here: https://www.barbaraapartmanheviz.hu/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. [`useEffect` is not executed on the server side](https://twitter.com/brian_d_vaughn/status/1055590462122156033) so the email won't be decoded before it's sent to the client.

It seems a bit needlessly complicated maybe. I'd say just put `{typeof window !== 'undefined' && decode(site.siteMetadata.email)}` in your JSX.

Of course there is no such thing as 100% protection. It's quite possible Google will index this email address. They do execute JavaScript during indexing. I'd strongly suspect most scrapers do not, but there might be some that do.

Comment: Thank you for the tip regarding `{typeof window !== 'undefined' && decode(site.siteMetadata.email)}`! It is a much easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried/considered https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-obfuscate ?
It doesn't encode data (e.g. email, tel) but reverses it in the DOM (and re-reverses with css).
Maybe not super secure but at least some obfuscation with minimal effort.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, seems to be a good option as well.

Comment: I wonder if it works properly with screen readers.